# Count lattice points enclosed in curve

Tags: geometry, number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-geometry

Let $$  (\log x_1)^2+ (\log x_2)^2 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + (\log x_n)^2= r $$

For $r=0,1,2,…$

The goal is to count the number of lattice points enclosed by the curve/surface for $r$. In this way the problem is a generalization of the Gauss circle problem.

> What is the exact solution or at least an approximate solution in dimension $2$?

I calculated that the first several terms in the sequence are $1,4,10,15,28,42,…$

The sequence seems to grow more slowly than when compared to the usual Gauss circle problem.

Comment: Is "log" the natural logarithm ?

Comment: yes :) @JeanMarie

Comment: @JeanMarie when $r=0$ there is 1 lattice point when $r=1$ there are 4 points etc. In this case $n=2$

Comment: I see you have now given these explanations in the text of the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I feel the necessity to represent some of these curves :

[image]

Fig. 1 : the first 5 curves for $r=1,\cdots 5$. In fact the "curve" for $r=0$ is reduced... to a single point $(1,1)$.

The asymptotic growth of these numbers $$N(r)=1,4,10,15,28,42,59,86,111,152,197,252,319,404,504,621,752,916,1112,1331,1589,1889,2233,2629,3081,3596,4192,4865,5634,6501,7480\cdots$$ look, on a "trial and error" basis to be approximately governed (on a logarithmic scale) by the following approximation :

$$\ln(N(r)) \approx 1.73r^{0.48}\tag{1}$$

(as represented on the figure below) :

Otherwise said :

$$N(r) \approx \exp(1.73r^{0.48})$$

[image]

Fig. 2 : Representation on a log. scale : exact figures (function $\log(N(r))$ represented as the blue curve, approximate values (RHS of (1)) represented by the red curve.

Comment: I [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3495373/305862) you were already interested by these curves some 4 years ago :)

Comment: My guess is that $\log N(r) = \frac{\pi }{2}\sqrt r  + \mathcal{O}(r^{1/4 + \varepsilon } )$.

Comment: @Gary  Very interesting remark : your formula is much more precise than mine (though in the same vein) ;  please give an answer explaining the bases of your "guess" : I will be happy to upvote it !

Comment: Thanks. I have no explanation at the moment. It was just a lucky guess supported by numerics.